# Email from apache in Gmail spam

Tags: php, apache, gmail, sendmail, spam

I send email from web page using php. Gmail users receive this email in spam. 
I have created DNS revers record and MX record. 
Here is code of email:

```
Delivered-To: someuser@gmail.com
Received: by 10.204.60.140 with SMTP id p12cs47940bkh;
        Thu, 26 Jan 2012 07:12:08 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.224.116.201 with SMTP id n9mr3202312qaq.16.1327590727329;
        Thu, 26 Jan 2012 07:12:07 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <apache@banana-app.com>
Received: from banana-app.com (banana-app.com. [107.6.86.26])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id t19si1801483qcx.182.2012.01.26.07.12.06;
        Thu, 26 Jan 2012 07:12:07 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of apache@banana-app.com designates 107.6.86.26 as permitted sender) client-ip=107.6.86.26;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of apache@banana-app.com designates 107.6.86.26 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=apache@banana-app.com
Received: from banana-app.com (banana-app.com [127.0.0.1])
    by banana-app.com (8.13.8/8.13.8) with ESMTP id q0QFC64q013520
    for <someuser@gmail.com>; Thu, 26 Jan 2012 10:12:06 -0500
Received: (from apache@localhost)
    by banana-app.com (8.13.8/8.13.8/Submit) id q0QFC6Rq013519;
    Thu, 26 Jan 2012 10:12:06 -0500
Message-Id: <201201261512.q0QFC6Rq013519@banana-app.com>
To: someuser@gmail.com
Subject: Password Recovery
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:Sendmail.php
From: info <info@banana-app.com>
Reply-To: info@banana-app.com
Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2012 17:12:06 +0200
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
MIME-Version: 1.0

=0A                Hello,=0A                <BR/>=0A                You=
 recently requested to reset the password for your account.=0A         =
<BR/>=0A                Banana=0A
```

Can someone please help me finding the problem?

Comment: Why do you send an HTML email for something as simple as a "reset password" email? Plaintext emails are much less likely to be flagged as SPAM.

Comment: "password recovery" or the like are a common phishing email subject, but I know this is not a highly technical response

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a library such as SwiftMailer. In libraries like that, the devs have given a lot of thought on topics like preventing to be marked as SPAM, so this might solve your problem.

Comment: Or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), it has also helped me avoid the spam folder (despite the heinous 1996-esque design of the project web site).

Comment: I use Zend_Mail to send emails.

Comment: Could it be the server you're sending from is blacklisted somewhere? Have you checked that?

Answer (score 1):

Many email providers detect emails that contain HTML content as SPAM.
Try again with simple text in the email-body to eliminate this option.

Comment: I have tried to send plain text email, tried to send email without "password". Same results, message in spam.

Comment: do you follow Bulk Senders Guidelines ?
https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126